# Request iAd button not showing up in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I want to get the iAd contract for my iOS app through iTunes connect. Unfortunately, it is not showing up anywhere in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking section in iTunes connect. The only things that are showing up are the free application contract that I already have and a  contract for paid applications that I still have to get.

I was wondering if I needed to get the paid applications contract beforehand and then I will be able to request the iAd contract because I am not seeing the request button for the iAd contract anywhere on my screen.

Comment: iAd is going away. Read https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: @rmaddy so there is no point to getting the iAd contract?

Comment: You can't get one any more.

Comment: oh ok thank you @rmaddy